# Awk copy digits to end of string

Tags: awk

At the moment I'm using

```
awk -F':' '{ j=$0; gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",j); print $0 j }'
```

Which will replicate all digits within the string and paste them to the end of the string, example -

input -

```
1Hello123
```

output -

```
1Hello1231123
```

However I only wish to replicated the numbers at the end of the string, not the start nor inbetween

So expected output in this scenario would be -

```
1Hello123123
```

In this output the 1 at the start hasn't been replicated.

Also must be done with AWK, not sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options:

```
$ echo 1Hello123 | awk '{sub(/[0-9]+$/,"&&",$0)} 1'
1Hello123123
```

or

```
$ echo 1Hello123 | awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+$/) {print $0 substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
1Hello123123
```

Comment: That first one is what I'd use but also ... or `awk '{j=$0; sub(/.*[^0-9]/,"",j); print $0 j}'`

Comment: Thanks appreciate the help :)